# Trying to use Notepad++ to remove Whitespace only on certain lines

Tags: regex, notepad++, whitespace

I'm trying to remove white spaces from lines beginning with a specific pattern. All other lines are to be untouched.
For example

```
ODBC;    DSN=Orac         lePacket1;      DBA=W;     ;APA=R
```

should be

```
ODBC;DSN=Oracle;DBA=W;APA=R
```

but

```
Table:     LPR_MONTH_VRNM_COM
```

should remain

```
Table:     LPR_MONTH_VRNM_COM
```

I though the solution would be pretty straightforward, but regular expressions in Notepad Plus are just not co-operating with me.

Comment: Soo which set of lines should have whitespace removed? You give us two kinds but don't say which is which.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern with nothing as replacement:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?!Table:))[^ \n\r]*\K +
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF6pG4/2)

pattern details:

```
(?:              # Two possible branches:

                 # A branch contiguous to the precedent match:
    \G           # anchor for the end of the last match or the start of the string
    (?!^)        # not at the start of the string (or the line)       

  |              # OR

    ^(?!Table:)  # A branch at the start of the line but not followed by "Table:"

)

                 # Then we reach the next space:
[^ \n\r]*        # all characters that are not a space or a newline

\K               # removes all that have been matched on the left from the result
[ ]+             # then only spaces will be removed.
```

Comment: Brilliant! One minor change to get it working. I had to take out the ?! in from of Table.

Comment: Your solution worked well for my post.
By the time I ran it, I had corrected the code that had created the initial conditions, your solution fixed.
I applied your fix to another issue, that required the "?!" To be removed.

In both cases you were very helpful,
Thanks for the tutorial btw. It was illuminating :)

Comment: @AnthonyBouttell you maybe should accept this obviously helpful answer.